# How to place one array inside another?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cordova

I've researched how to add an array inside another array but the result wasn't quite what I expected. I tried using 'array_push' and 'array_merge' but neither one solved my problem. Here's the code I have so far:

```
else if ($_GET['type'] == "listaJogos") {
//echo 'Tipo de operação: ' . $_GET['type'] . '<br>';

$campeonato_id = $_GET['campeonato'];

//Query que retorna a NOME_TIME, ID, DATA_HORA, TB_COTACAO_ID
$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(timee.nome_time ORDER BY timee.nome_time SEPARATOR ' X ') AS nome_time, 
        partida.id, partida.data_hora, partida.tb_cotacao_id 
        FROM tb_partida AS partida, tb_time AS timee, tb_partida_time AS partidaTime 
        WHERE (partida.id = tb_partida_id && timee.id = tb_time_id) 
        AND (partida.flag_ativo = 1 AND partida.flag_cancelado <> 1 AND partida.flag_finalizado <> 1) 
        AND partida.tb_campeonato_id = $campeonato_id 
        GROUP BY partida.id";

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `tb_cotacao` WHERE `id` = ";


$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $registros[] = array('partida' => $reg);

    $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2 . $reg['tb_cotacao_id']);

    //$registros[] = array('partida' => mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC));

    array_push($registros, mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
}

$saida = json_encode(array('json' => $registros));

echo $saida;
```

}

The code above gives me the output below:

```
"json": [
{
  "partida": {
    "nome_time": "Acreano\r X Flamengo\r",
    "id": "4",
    "data_hora": "2016-09-03 14:00:00",
    "tb_cotacao_id": "4"
  }
},
{
  "id": "4",
  "casa": "1.23",
  "empate": "2.13",
  "fora": "1.23",
  "gol_meio": "6.00",
  "mais_2gm": "7.00",
  "menos_3gm": "7.67",
  "ambas_marcam": "0.00",
  "casa_empate": "6.00",
  "fora_empate": "7.67",
  "casa_marca": "6.00",
  "fora_marca": "76.00",
  "casa_ou_fora": "76.00",
  "casavence_foramarca": "76.00",
  "foravence_casamarca": "7.00",
  "casavence_zero": "67.00",
  "foravence_zero": "67.00"
}]
```

What I need is the array I'm trying to push to be inside 'partida', like this:

```
"json": [
{
  "partida": {
    "nome_time": "Acreano\r X Flamengo\r",
    "id": "4",
    "data_hora": "2016-09-03 14:00:00",
    "tb_cotacao_id": "4"
    "cotacoes": {
       "id": "4",
       "casa": "1.23",
       "empate": "2.13",
       "fora": "1.23",
       "gol_meio": "6.00",
       "mais_2gm": "7.00",
       "menos_3gm": "7.67",
       "ambas_marcam": "0.00",
       "casa_empate": "6.00",
       "fora_empate": "7.67",
       "casa_marca": "6.00",
       "fora_marca": "76.00",
       "casa_ou_fora": "76.00",
       "casavence_foramarca": "76.00",
       "foravence_casamarca": "7.00",
       "casavence_zero": "67.00",
       "foravence_zero": "67.00"
    }
  }
}]
```

I'd really appreciate if someone can give me a hand with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 array_push($registros[0]['partida'], mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

use this

modify your 3rd line from last

Comment: Thank's for answering. I've tried that and I've got an error: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in.

Comment: It worked but not completely. The output was this: [link](http://pastebin.com/UEM7r6wA)